# How to use an ArrayAdapter with Parcelables?

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, android-adapter, parcelable, custom-adapter

I'm trying to build a vey simple example with a `ListView`, an `ArrayAdapter` and `Parcelable`.

In my example there is a 1st `Activity` in which the user types his name, address and country. This data is then parceled and sent through and extra to a 2nd `Activity`. (I know I don't need to parcel to send this amount of data but I`m trying to practice parceling with a very simple example)

On the 2nd `Activity` the data is presented in a `List` that uses an `ArrayAdapter`.

I revised the code over and over, tried all sorts of examples but still could't figure out what is wrong with my code. Could someone help me out please??

Here is the code:

**MAIN ACTIVITY:**

```
        package com.example.marcelshimabukuro.treino_lista_inflater_adapter_bean;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    public Context mContext;

    public EditText etNome, etEndereco, etPais;
    public Button mButton;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mContext = this;

        loadComponents();

        loadDadosDeUsuario();

        loadButtonActions();

    }


    private void loadComponents() {

        mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btActivity2);

        etNome = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etNome1);
        etEndereco = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etEndereco1);
        etPais = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPais1);

    }

    public Usuarios[] loadDadosDeUsuario() {


        Usuarios[] usuariosArray = new Usuarios[3];

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

            Usuarios usuarios = new Usuarios();

            //Pegar dados que usuario digitar no TextView e jogar no Array
            usuarios.setNome(etNome.getText().toString());
            usuarios.setEndereço(etEndereco.getText().toString());
            usuarios.setPais(etPais.getText().toString());

            usuariosArray[i] = usuarios;

        }

        return usuariosArray;


    }


    private void loadButtonActions() {

        mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                //Mandar dados com Intent para outra actitivy
                //Instanciar var Intent
                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, ListaActivity.class);

                //Colocar os extras no meu intent para mandar oara a proxima activity
                intent.putExtra("dadosdeusuario", loadDadosDeUsuario());

                //Iniciar nova activity
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });



    }
}
```

**USER ACTIVITY:**

```
package com.example.marcelshimabukuro.treino_lista_inflater_adapter_bean;

import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

/**
 * Created by marcelshimabukuro on 7/25/15.
 */

//Classe Usuario para conter a minha estrutura de dados
public class Usuarios implements Parcelable {

    public String mNome, mEndereço, mPais;

    //Constructor
    public Usuarios() {

    }

    public String getNome() {
        return mNome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        mNome = nome;
    }

    public String getEndereço() {
        return mEndereço;
    }

    public void setEndereço(String endereço) {
        mEndereço = endereço;
    }

    public String getPais() {
        return mPais;
    }

    public void setPais(String pais) {
        mPais = pais;
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(mNome);
        dest.writeString(mEndereço);
        dest.writeString(mPais);
    }


    public static final Creator<Usuarios> CREATOR = new Creator<Usuarios>() {
        @Override
        public Usuarios createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Usuarios(in);
        }

        @Override
        public Usuarios[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Usuarios[size];
        }
    };

    protected Usuarios(Parcel in) {
        mNome = in.readString();
        mEndereço = in.readString();
        mPais = in.readString();
    }
}
```

**LIST ACTIVITY:**

```
package com.example.marcelshimabukuro.treino_lista_inflater_adapter_bean;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;


public class ListaActivity extends ListActivity {

    public Context mContext;
    public ListView mListView;

    public Usuarios[] mUsuariosArray;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_lista);

        mContext = this;

        loadComponents();

        loadList();

        loadAdapter();

    }


    private void loadComponents() {

        mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvLista3);

    }

    private void loadList() {

        Intent intent = getIntent();

        Parcelable[] parcelables = intent.getParcelableArrayExtra("dadosdeusuario");

       mUsuariosArray = Arrays.copyOf(parcelables, parcelables.length, Usuarios[].class);


    }

    private void loadAdapter() {

        ArrayList<Usuarios> usuariosArrayList = new ArrayList<Usuarios>();

        //Declarar var adapter
        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, usuariosArrayList);

        //Iniciar meu adapter
        mListView.setAdapter(adapter);



    }

}
```

**ADAPTER ACTIVITY:**

```
package com.example.marcelshimabukuro.treino_lista_inflater_adapter_bean;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by marcelshimabukuro on 8/15/15.
 */
public class ArrayAdapter extends android.widget.ArrayAdapter<Usuarios> {

    public TextView mNome, mEndereço, mPais;

    //Constructor
    public ArrayAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Usuarios> usuariosArrayList) {
        super(context,0 , usuariosArrayList);
    }



    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        //Pegar dado de cada item nesta posição
        Usuarios usuarios = getItem(position);

        //Se nenhuma view ja foi inflada
        if (convertView == null) {

            //Inflar a lista usando meu layout de itens
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.itens_de_lista, parent, false);
        }

        //Casting de meus objs de tela atrave da var converView
        mNome = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvNome);
        mEndereço = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvEndereço);
        mPais = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvPais);

        //o TextView da minha lista sera = ao valor da var String correspondente da classe Usuarios
        mNome.setText(usuarios.mNome);
        mEndereço.setText(usuarios.mEndereço);
        mPais.setText(usuarios.mPais);

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the issue you are facing?

Answer (score 0):

In `ListActivity`, you are storing the data received from `MainActivity` in instance variable `mUsuariosArray`, but you are not using `mUsuariosArray` while creating the adapter.  Instead you are using an empty array list.

```
ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, usuariosArrayList);
```

Your code should be something like below:

```
ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mUsuariosArray);
```

Comment: Thanks Wand Maker but I tried this and it did not quite work. I made a few changes on the loadDadosDeUsuario metho cuz I think it was returning an empty array. But even after this it is still giving me errors. I suspect the app is being killed in the loadButtonActions method when it loads the intent. I ran the debug there and there is a certain point where it says that "parcellable data = null". Don`t knot if it has anything to do with it. I will post again the updated code an the error log cat underneath.